# Is there an index of mathematical objects by notation?

Tags: reference-request, notation, reference-works

I am looking for something like an encyclopaedia of mathematics, but with the main difference from regular references of such kind being that *one could use it to search for mathematical objects by entering in the mathematical notation of the object* instead of, say, a common name using the usual symbols of a natural language. A quick example would be typing something like `\mathbb R^3` into some engine and having it bring up a main, short article on euclidean $3$-space, with links to other articles dealing more with this object, etc.

My search so far has yielded only the usual kind of index or list, and I do really hope that someone has curated the kind of list I'm looking for.

Comment: There's such an index  (without the links to definitions) for latex symbols, and it would be a cool project to do something similar for general math symbols.

Comment: [Wikipedia's 
Glossary of Mathematical Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols) seems close to what you want. Can you elaborate on what you're looking for that that doesn't do?

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks, but that is just a very short list of some common *notational* symbols. For example, I don't think of parentheses as mathematical objects -- they're just a convenient typographic device that are an artefact of our system of writing; also, the list does not include something as basic as an euclidean space. It is a very far cry from the kind of thing I want, as described above. The kind of thing I want should contain references to *objects* in many subfields of mathematics -- different major examples of spaces, groups, fields, algebras, functions, etc.

Comment: @MarkS. TLDR Just think of it like this: Can you check out what object is being referred to by notation you're not familiar with in, say, a monograph that is not your specialty in the list? If yes, then it is probably the kind of list I want.

Comment: Got it. That clarification will help people answer with what you're looking for (if it exists). I fear that things like Google and ChatGPT may be the best non-human sources for answers to totally unbounded questions about mathematics objects like "what is PSL2(Z) in math?" when you don't know it's related to Linear Algebra.

Comment: (I guess approach0 may also find things like MathSE questions where people ask for something to be explained, but that's limited to things people have asked about in reasonably similar LaTeX)

Comment: @MarkS. In fact I thought of Google first, naturally, but it clearly cannot recognise LaTex commands -- otherwise it would have been the perfect fit! This aspect is very important as most of these objects are not always in the Latin characters that one may input in commonplace search engines like Google's -- hence my request for a dedicated math engine of the sort I requested.

Comment: But Google answers questions like "what does latex \wp mean in math" and "what does \mathbb R^3 mean" just fine. (And if you only saw the symbol and didn't know the TeX code for $\wp$, Detexify would tell you.)